# Insert new row and copy a cell to other cell

Tags: excel, vba

In the column D1:D50000 in various cells i have value as 1.
I want to check in which cell of column D value is 1 and insert a row above all the cells having value as 1, and i want to copy a cell value from M1 to all the new inserted rows first cell in the left

Answer (score 0):

Here, my solution for your problem.

```
Public Sub insertRow()

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim rowCount As Long

    'Set start row and end row
    row = 1
    rowCount = 50000

    With Sheets("sheetname")

        'Loop until to last row
        Do While row <= rowCount

            'If D cell is equal with 1.
            If .Range("D" & row) = 1 Then

                'Insert new rwo above that row
                Rows(row).EntireRow.Insert

                'Copy value from M cell of current to first cell of newly inserted row
                .Range("A" & row) = .Range("M" & row + 1)

                'Increase row
                row = row + 1

                'Increase row count
                rowCount = rowCount + 1

            End If

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```